# after upload the image by using uploadify refresh the images

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

Actually i am trying to refresh the images when i upload the image by using Uploadify script.Image upload successfully but onUploadSuccess java script function not triggered although in my query.uploadify.js file

```
onUploadSuccess  // Triggered when a file is uploaded successfully
```

please can you help me.Thanks

My java Script is:

```
 $(function () {
                $("#file_upload").uploadify({
                    'swf': 'Resources/ImgUpload/uploadify.swf',
                    'uploader': 'VBHandler.ashx',
                    'cancelImg': 'Resources/ImgUpload/cancel.png',
                    'buttonText': 'Add Photos',
                    'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                    'multi': true,
                    'auto': true,
                    'formData': {
                        "id": "<%=HfID.Value%>",
                        'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
                            // Load the swfupload settings
                            alert('upload');
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I am using version Uploadify v3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onUploadSuccess` must not be in `formData`.So try this one:

```
 $(function () {
                $("#file_upload").uploadify({
                    'swf': 'Resources/ImgUpload/uploadify.swf',
                    'uploader': 'VBHandler.ashx',
                    'cancelImg': 'Resources/ImgUpload/cancel.png',
                    'buttonText': 'Add Photos',
                    'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                    'multi': true,
                    'auto': true,
                    'formData': {
                        "id": "<%=HfID.Value%>"
                    },
                    'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
                            // Load the swfupload settings
                            alert('upload');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks brother i think that's i am missing.